# Geometry question about finding side length of a triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image: Diagram]

I'm not getting anywhere with this question; I feel like I'm supposed to use similar triangles to find some side lengths but I haven't been able to find any. I let $EF=x$ and found that $AP=PD=\frac{5}{8}x$, but haven't gotten any further than that. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Hint: according to GeoGebra, $m\angle C=30^\circ$.

Comment: How do you prove it though?

Comment: Dunno.  But that's the angle that makes the line from B through the midpoint of the altitude bisect the opposite side in the ratio of 4:1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nearly there! Similar triangles / side length ratios is all that you need.

**Hint:** $BPD, BEF$ are also similar, so $BD:DF = ?:?$.

**Hint:** $ABD, CAD$ are also similar.

---

> $BD:DF:FC = 5:3:12$, which means that $BD : DC = 1:3$
>  $ ABD, CAD$ are similar $\Rightarrow BD : AD : DC = 1 : \sqrt{3} : 3$.
>  So $ \angle C = 30^ \circ$ and $AD = 15 \sin 30^ \circ$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: use barycentric method. In **any** triangle:

[image]

In our triangle $BC$ is divided by $D$ as $1:3$, therefore $C$ is $30$ degrees

For method details see the [article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/triangles-and-particle-magic/) I wrote several years ago.